# Issues with validating MVVM WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, validation, mvvm

I am trying to implement validation within a WPF application using MVVM, I believe that I have the validation set up correctly but when I test it it doesn't seem to give me a red outline on the text box as many examples I've found online do (Such as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOHDie8BdGI).

For simplicity I have narrowed it down to one criterion which is that the textbox for Forename is not left blank and removed the other properties. The only difference I am aware of between the examples in guides I have been using and my own application is that my Model is held on a server whereas the View and ViewModel are client side, could this be what is causing the issues?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been struggling with this for a few days now, thanks!

### RegistrationModel (Server side)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ScrumManagementWCFServices.Services.Registration
{
    [DataContract]
    public class RegistrationModel : IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string forename;

        [DataMember]
        public string Forename
        {
            get 
            { 
                return forename;
            }
            set
            {
                forename = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Forename");
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IDataErrorInfo Members

        string System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo.Error
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        string System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
        {
            get
            {
                return GetValidationError(propertyName);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Validation

        static readonly string[] ValidatedProperties = {/* "Email", */"Forename"/*, "Surname", "Password", "ConPassword"*/};

        public bool IsValid
        {
            get
            {
                foreach (string property in ValidatedProperties)
                    if (GetValidationError(property) != null)
                        return false;

                return true;
            }
        }

        string GetValidationError(String propertyName)
        {
            string error = null;

            switch (propertyName)
            {
                case "Forename":
                    error = validateForename();
                    break;
            }
            return error;
        }

        private string validateForename()
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Forename))
            {
                return "Customer name cannot be empty.";
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

### RegistrationPage (View - Client side)

```
<Page x:Class="ScrumManagementApplication.Pages.LoginAndRegistrationPage.View.RegistrationPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScrumManagementApplication.Pages.LoginAndRegistrationPage.ViewModel"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300"
    Title="RegistrationView" Width="300">

    <Page.Resources>
        <local:RegistrationViewModel x:Key="DataContext"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="#FFC0CAEC" DataContext="{StaticResource DataContext}" Margin="10">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding RegistrationModel.Forename, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

### RegistrationViewModel (Client side)

```
using ScrumManagementApplication.WCFRegistrationServiceReference;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.ComponentModel;
using ScrumManagementApplication.Pages.LoginAndRegistrationPage.View;
using System.Windows;

namespace ScrumManagementApplication.Pages.LoginAndRegistrationPage.ViewModel
{
    public class RegistrationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public RegistrationViewModel()
        {
            RegistrationModel = new RegistrationModel()
            {
                Forename = "Rick"
            };
        }

        public RegistrationModel RegistrationModel
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expose a wrapper property and implement `IDataErrorInfo` on the view model or bind to the model directly. Validation will not work with bindings like `{Binding RegistrationModel.Forename}`

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify things a bit with the [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx). For example, if you decorate your `Forename` property with a [`RequiredAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), you will see your required red error outline on your `TextBox` when the field is left empty:

```
[DataMember]
[Required(ErrorMessage="Customer name cannot be empty.")]
public string Forename
{
    get 
    { 
        return forename;
    }
    set
    {
        Validator.ValidateProperty(value, 
            new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "Forename" });
        forename = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Forename");
    }
}
```

You can find out more details from the [Using Data Annotations to Customize Data Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590(VS.95).aspx) page on MSDN. You could of course refactor this to use a single method that both validates and notifies the 
`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Comment: Thank for your answer Sheridan, this came in useful though it didn't solve the issue with having the validation work. It will definitely come in useful in the future for efficiency, thank you